# Filling a region in a plot changes color in legend

Tags: color, legending, filling

I'd like to mark a region in my plot and after some research in the internet I found the solution I was looking for using the Filling option.

```
f1 [x_] := Sin[x]

f2 [x_] := Cos[x]

lb := -.4

ub := .3

f1[0]

f2[0]

Plot[ { lb, f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0 - Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Join[ {None}, ColorData[97, "ColorList"]], 
 Filling -> {1 -> {ub, LightBlue}}, PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "Cos"}]
```

The result is here

[image]

As you can see, the label "Sin" has no color and "Cos" has the color of "Sin" (because Cos[0]=1.0).
Any ideas?

Thanks, Jörg

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
PlotLegends -> {None, "Sin", "Cos"}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.
Stupid me.